# Why is React's onChange event not fired on Selenium WebDriver's SendKeys in IE 11?

Tags: reactjs, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

We have a relatively simple React component with an `input` element in it:

```
export class MyInput extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    function log(e) {
      console.log(`Event: ${e.type}, isTrusted: ${e.isTrusted}, input value: ${e.target.value}`, e);
    }

    this.rawInput.addEventListener("change", log);
    this.rawInput.addEventListener("input", log);
  }

  onChanged(e) {
    console.log("raw-input.onChanged: e.target.value", e.target.value);

    this.props.onChanged(e.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="my-class">
        <input
          value={this.props.value}
          onChange={this.onChanged.bind(this)}
          ref={(input) => { this.rawInput = input; }}
          />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Basically, this is just a slightly wrapped `input` element, while the logging added on top is for debug purposes.

It handles typing just fine in regular usage, it also handles `SendKeys` under Selenium WebDriver in Chrome, Firefox and IE 11 (provided that WebDriver's `EnableNativeEvents` is `true`).

However, when run in Internet Explorer 11 by WebDriver and with `EnableNativeEvents = false`, the `onChanged` event is not fired when `SendKeys` is executed. What's most weird is that the HTML `input` event is fired. Below is the console output:
[image: Missing onChange under WebDriver]

Notice that the input's `value` is changing while "test" is being typed, but there's no `onChange`.

Below is an expanded `input` event in case of WebDriver:
[image: Detailed input event from WebDriver]

If a user then types via keyboard in the same input, the `onChange` event is there:
[image: onChange is successfully fired on real typing]

Below is an expanded `input` event in case of user typing:
[image: Detailed input event when user is typing]

Close analysis shows that the only difference in the `input` events is that under WebDriver `isTrusted: false`, while on real typing `isTrusted: true`.

The question is why in the first case `onChange` events are not fired by React?

I assume this is because React skips events with `isTrusted: false` because this means they are simulated, not real user events. However, I was not able to find any proof for this. If it's the case, would you mind providing a link to a post or a line in React sources that handles it?

- React: 16.7.0
- Selenium.WebDriver.IEDriver: 3.14.0

Comment: Did you try to compare event objects from both actions?

Comment: @fard, if you mean comparing WebDriver's SendKeys and user typing - yes, I have compared the objects, and at least on the first level of properties the only difference is the `isTrusted` property value

Comment: I mean whole event object

Comment: @fard, added to the question. On the first level, I don't see any differences other than `isTrusted`. Not sure if it makes sense to expand deeper. Events' `srcElement` and `target` point to the same correct input element. Should I investigate something specific?

Comment: The `onChange` event is not fired because the driver doesn't emulate this event when `EnableNativeEvents` is false. This has nothing to do with `isTrusted`. The issue lies with the [injected code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/atoms/keyboard.js) used by the driver.

Comment: @FlorentB., thank you, it's an interesting thought. However, I would not expect any driver to emulate this event, as this is a React-specific synthetic event. As far as I can tell, React handles the raw `input` and `change` events from HTML DOM, and converts them into its own `onChange` event. From HTML DOM perspective, I don't see any differences: both user typing and web driver `SendKeys` fire only `input` events in IE 11 (while focus stays in the input element). I would say the web driver behavior seems fine.

Answer (score 7):

When setting the `nativeEvents` capability to `false` (which is what you’re setting with the `EnableNativeEvents` property), you’re telling the IE driver to use JavaScript to simulate the events. Events simulated via JavaScript
[cannot have the isTrusted property set to true](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted). That property is designed to detect exactly the scenario you’re experiencing. The driver implementations for Firefox and Chrome are produced and maintained by the vendors for those browsers (Mozilla and Google, respectively), and as such, those drivers have access to internals of the browser in ways that the IE driver does not (and likely never will) have. If React is indeed keying off that property to fire the `onChanged` event, then the proper thing to do here is set `EnableNativeEvents = true`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. It confirms my general assumptions. Any chance you know if React does filter by `isTrusted`? I wasn't able to find anything like this in the sources, so I wonder if something else is getting in the way